# Problem in installing spotify in Ubuntu 14.04 LTS 64-bit

Tags: software-installation, spotify

I followed the following instructions to install spotify as mentioned [here](https://www.spotify.com/int/download/linux/).

1. `sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys 0DF731E45CE24F27EEEB1450EFDC8610341D9410`
2. `sudo apt-get update`
3. `sudo apt-get install spotify-client`

But I get the following error:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package spotify-client
```

I have read that this problem occurs on 32-bit system but I am on a 64-bit system. I don't know why this problem is occurring. Is there any other way to get spotify on my system?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You missed step 2 of the instructions you linked to:

```
# 2. Add the Spotify repository
echo deb http://repository.spotify.com stable non-free | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/spotify.list
```

That is an essential step since it adds Spotify's repository If you don't add it, you can't use it so can't find the package. So, just run the command above, and them continue with steps 2 and 3 from your question.